# Flash AS3 Event propagation

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I wonder if you can help with something I imagine is relatively simple - but amazingly frustrating!

I have a list of movie clips that each contain a button with an instance name Mbtn.  I would like the button to appear only when the mouse hovers over the parent clip.  The structure is basically a parent clip called pcs, 5 child clips (named below) each containing a button with an instance name of mBtn.  here is my code -

```
hr_pc.mBtn.visible=false;
m_pc.mBtn.visible=false;
me_pc.mBtn.visible=false;
d_pc.mBtn.visible=false;
di_pc.mBtn.visible=false;




pcs.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, mOver);
pcs.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, mOut);

function mOver(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
var overNow = evt.currentTarget.name;
overNow.mBtn.visible=true;


}
function mOut(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
var overNot = evt.currentTarget.name;
overNot.mBtn.visible=false;
}
```

I'm sure there's a much better way to do this - any suggestions very gratefully received!

Thanks
Paul

Comment: What exactly are you asking? All I understand from your post is the code you posted is "frustrating".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
evt.currentTarget.name
```

means that, right now, you are targeting your container object (`pcs`), and not the contents (`hr_pc, m_pc` etc). This is the key difference between `evt.target` and `evt.currentTarget`. If you trace out the currentTarget name, it will be identical for each intended target. 
So, to rectify,you can certainly make this work with

```
evt.target.name
```

You may have issues, however, if you mouse over the button, as the target will no longer be the buttons direct parent (it will be the button itself), and the button is likely to trigger `visible=false` again.

I would probably go a different direction with this: write a class that contains the button and its own listeners. This would be a good plan if there is a lot of shared behavior (but depending on your needs, may not be).

So, yeah, read up on [currentTarget vs target](http://www.wastedpotential.com/?p=10)

Comment: and for real, @The_asMan is right on: timeline code is bad, and to be avoided at all cost.

Comment: Isn't `evt.target.name` just a String? Should be `evt.target' to get reference to DisplayObject.

Comment: @alxx = i'm referencing the OP's post - he seems to be making use of the instance name in his logic, and I'm just following along with that. But, yes, you are definitely right = the name prop is just a string.